# NextJS 13 app router doesn't refresh data on update with router.push

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering, next.js13, app-router

I have NextJS 13 app with app router. Which displays a table (shadcn UI) data-table with server side pagination. I have a create button that goes to a create page, And I can create a new entry into the table. On success of the API I do a

```js
router.push("/path")
```

that goes back to the table page. This shows a new entry in my table. But when I do the same after going to an edit page and update an existing row and do a router push the data doesn't get updated.

**Edit Page**

```js
import EditBrandForm from "@/components/brand/edit-brand-form";
import { DashboardHeader } from "@/components/header";
import { BASE_API_URL } from "@/constants/constants";
import { BRANDS_ENDPOINT } from "@/constants/routes";
import { getAccessTokenCookie } from "@/lib/session";
import { Brand } from "@/types/brand";
import { Metadata } from "next";

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Edit brand",
};

export default async function EditBrand({
  params,
}: {
  params: { id: number };
}) {
  const apiResponse = await fetch(
    `${BASE_API_URL}${BRANDS_ENDPOINT}${params.id}`,
    {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${getAccessTokenCookie()}`,
      },
    }
  );
  const brandResponse: Brand = await apiResponse.json();

  return (
    <div>
      <DashboardHeader heading="Edit brand"></DashboardHeader>
      <EditBrandForm brand={brandResponse} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**EditBrandForm**

```js
"use client";

import { brandFormSchema } from "@/lib/validations/brand";
import { Input } from "../ui/input";
import * as z from "zod";
import * as React from "react";
import { useToast } from "../ui/use-toast";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod";
import { brandService } from "@/services/brand.service";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { Button } from "../ui/button";
import { Icons } from "../icons";
import { Brand } from "@/types/brand";

type FormData = z.infer<typeof brandFormSchema>;

interface EditBrandFormProps {
  brand: Brand;
}

export default function EditBrandForm({ brand }: EditBrandFormProps) {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState<boolean>(false);
  const router = useRouter();

  const { toast } = useToast();

  const defaultValues: FormData = {
    name: brand.name,
    website: brand.website,
  };

  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
    clearErrors,
  } = useForm<FormData>({
    resolver: zodResolver(brandFormSchema),
    defaultValues,
  });

  async function onSubmit(data: FormData) {
    setIsLoading(true);
    const apiResponse = await brandService.editBrand(
      brand.id,
      data.name,
      data.website
    );
    setIsLoading(false);
    if (!apiResponse.error) {
      router.push("/brands");
    } else {
      toast({
        variant: "destructive",
        title: "An unexpected error occured.",
      });
    }
  }

  return (
    <form
      onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
      className="px-2 py-8 flex w-full flex-col space-y-6 sm:w-[350px]"
    >
      <div className="grid w-full max-w-sm items-center gap-1.5">
        <Input
          {...register("name")}
          type="text"
          placeholder="Brand name"
          onChange={() => {
            clearErrors("name");
          }}
        />
        {errors?.name && (
          <p className="px-1 text-xs text-red-600">{errors.name.message}</p>
        )}
      </div>
      <Input type="text" placeholder="Brand website" {...register("website")} />
      <Button disabled={isLoading} className="w-1/2">
        {isLoading && <Icons.spinner className="mr-2 h-4 w-4 animate-spin" />}
        Update
      </Button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

**Data table Page**

```js
import { BASE_API_URL } from "@/constants/constants";
import { BrandsTableShell } from "@/components/brands-table-shell";
import CreateButton from "@/components/create-button";
import { DashboardHeader } from "@/components/header";
import { getAccessTokenCookie } from "@/lib/session";
import { Metadata } from "next";
import { BRANDS_ENDPOINT } from "@/constants/routes";

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Brands",
  description: "Brands",
};

interface IndexPageProps {
  searchParams: {
    [key: string]: string | string[] | undefined;
  };
}

export default async function DashboardPage({ searchParams }: IndexPageProps) {
  const { page, per_page } = searchParams;

  // Number of items per page
  const pageSize = typeof per_page === "string" ? parseInt(per_page) : 10;
  // Current page number
  const pageNumber = page === undefined ? 1 : page;

  const apiResponse = await fetch(
    `${BASE_API_URL}${BRANDS_ENDPOINT}?page=${pageNumber}&size=${pageSize}`,
    {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${getAccessTokenCookie()}`,
      },
    }
  );
  const brands = await apiResponse.json();
  const pageCount = brands.total_pages;

  return (
    <div>
      <DashboardHeader heading="Brands" text="Create and manage brands">
        <CreateButton text="Add brand" route="brands/create" />
      </DashboardHeader>
      <div className="px-2 py-10">
        <BrandsTableShell data={brands.results} pageCount={pageCount} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a

```
router.refresh()
```

after push fixes it. @joulev from the discord NextJS server pointed me to [this](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/54075) article which explains why this is required in more details.